# In Ionic 4, an observable from a store selector doesn’t refresh the UI ! Why?

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngrx, angular-changedetection

A simple page with data and async pipe is not reloaded when observable emits new value.

I created a blank page with Ionic CLI.
I add the Network plugin.
In the home page I listen network changes, the console logs the changes but UI is not refreshed …

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Network
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.page.ts

```js
test$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private network: Network) {}

    /**
     *
     */
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.test$ = concat(
          this.network.onConnect().pipe(debounceTime(2000)),
          this.network.onDisconnect()
      ).pipe(
          tap(() => console.log('Connection changed !')),
          map(() => this.network.type),
          tap(type => console.log('Connection type', type))
      );
  }
```

home.page.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    The world is your oyster.
    <p *ngIf="test$|async as test">{{test}}</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I run the app with `ionic cordova run android -lcs` (on my device connected by USB)
I change the network type by disableing the wifi. The console logs :

```
Connection changed !
home.page.ts:26 Connection type 4g
```

The UI is not refreshed ...
What’s wrong ???

Answer (score 1):

Had to test it myself to confirm my suspicion, which is that the plugin runs outside of Angular change detection. So even assigning the value to a string variable like...

```ts
this.network.onConnect().pipe(
  map(() => this.network.type)
).subscribe(type => this.test$ = type)
```

and displaying with `{{ test$ }}` doesn't work

So we can instead trigger change detection manually by importing `ChangeDetectorRef`, inject it in constructor and call `detectChanges()`:

```ts
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

constructor(
  private network: Network,
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.test$ = concat(
    this.network.onConnect().pipe(debounceTime(2000)),
    this.network.onDisconnect()
  ).pipe(
    map(() => this.network.type),
    tap(() => this.cdr.detectChanges())
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing happens.
Displayed value does not change when I disable the wifi